# How to catch unauthorized exception when accessing SharePoint with JCSOM

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

When a user is in group onOperationSucceeded is called otherwise an unauthorized exception "Request failed. Access denied. You do not have permission..." How can I accomplish that the catch block is getting hit?

try {
                var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();

```
            groupCollection = clientContext.get_web().get_siteGroups();
            group = groupCollection.getByName("VR-Administrators"); 

            users = group.get_users();
            clientContext.load(group);
            clientContext.load(users);
            currentUser = clientContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
            clientContext.load(currentUser);

            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, onOperationSucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, onOperationFailed));
        }
        catch(msg)
        {
            alert("Failed!" + msg);
        }
```

Comment: So your catch block does not get hit? Do you get any error message in onOperationFailed function?

Comment: No - onOperationFailed does not get hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn168907.aspx) executes the current pending request **asynchronously** on the server:

```
SP.ClientContext.executeQueryAsync(succeededCallback, failedCallback)
```

If the request is failed to execute, `failedCallback` is invoked.

In your case, the following code demonstrates how to  handle `System.UnauthorizedAccessException` exception:

```
function onOperationFailed(sender,args)
{

   if(args.get_errorTypeName() == "System.UnauthorizedAccessException")
   {
        //Handle UnauthorizedAccessException here..
   }

}
```